saving screenshots to ~/Pictures without a dialogue window using gnome-screenshot in Mint 22
I'm running a fresh install of Mint 22. When I take a screenshot (via keyboard shortcut), a dialog appears to ask what I want to do with it (copy to clipboard, save to file, which file name...).
I prefer the Ubuntu behaviour: just save the image to ~/Pictures directly in a timestamped file, no questions asked.
I've tried setting /org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/auto-save-directory to /home/me/Pictures/ using dconf (as suggested in a few places on-line) but it has no effect.
I've noticed that while the gnome-screenshot dialogue is open that gnome-screenshot was started with the --window switch. Is that hard-coded somewhere or can it be changed, e.g., to add -f somefilename.png?
How do I configure gnome-screenshot to skip the dialogue and save the image to a file directly?

gnome-screenshot --file=filename.jpg is how you do it, but I don't know what is launching it from the GUI...  But yes, that is the way to save direct to file.  Maybe just go to keyboard settings and set a key command with that command.

@JayCravens it's a decent suggestion, thank you. I could do that, but I'd like to leave a more by-the-book answer for posterity, if for no other reason, than because it seems frustratingly hard to tease out how it should actually be done for a problem as simple as this. Perhaps cinnamon devs pick this up and get ideas on how to improve something a bit, as well.
